# SQL into PHP array for easy table creation

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays, html-table

My DB schema is

```sql
CREATE TABLE "tests" (
"id" integer UNIQUE,
"type" integer NULL,
"monitor" integer NULL,
"name" varchar(255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
);

CREATE TABLE "summary" (
"id" integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"testid" integer NULL,
"timestamp" datetime NULL,
"total" integer NULL,
);
```

My SQL query is:

```sql
SELECT "s"."testid", AVG(total) AS "total" , DATE(timestamp) AS "d"
FROM "summary" AS "s"
INNER JOIN "tests" AS "t" ON s.testid = t.id
WHERE (timestamp >= date('now', '-7 days'))
GROUP BY "d", "testid" ORDER BY "d" DESC
```

Which returns the following data example data:

```
Test A | 2014-07-30 | 100
Test B | 2014-07-30 | 99
Test C | 2014-07-30 | 98
Test A | 2014-07-31 | 100
Test B | 2014-07-31 | 99
Test C | 2014-07-31 | 98
Test A | 2014-08-01 | 100
Test B | 2014-08-01 | 99
Test C | 2014-08-01 | 98
```

My desired end goal is to have a HTML table that displays the above data like this:

```
Test Name | 2014-07-30 | 2014-07-31 | 2014-08-01
------------------------------------------------  
Test A         100          100          100
Test B          99           99           99
Test C          98           98           98
```

I am struggling to create the required PHP array from the SQL to then loop through and create the table.

Any help would be most gratefully received!

Comment: Whats your sql database?

Comment: `SELECT testcol,(CASE WHEN date='2014-07-30' THEN intcol ELSE 0 END) as '2014-07-30,(CASE WHEN date='2014-07-31' THEN intcol ELSE 0 END) as '2014-07-31',......etc FROM t GROUP BY testcol`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't write any code it is harder for me to help you.

The basic idea is this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table");
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

echo "<tr><td>$row['your_cell_name']</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

**When you will upload your code I will be able to help you more.**

I assumed that you use `php` with `mysql` server.

**edit:**

What I would do is:

1. find the distinct items at the test name column
2. find the distinct dates
3. Use basic SQL `WHERE` to find for example test A at 2014-07-30 and echo it into `<td>` tag

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM summary");
echo "<table><tr><td>Test Name</td>"
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    foreach($row as $date)
    {
        echo "<td>{$date}</td>"
    }
}
echo "</tr><tr>";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT testid FROM summary");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    foreach($row as $testid){
        echo "<td>{$testid}</td>";
        $sum_query = "YOUR QUERY FOR THE SCORE OF THE TEST";//you can use $testid to find all of the summery at the distinct date
        //Hope you understand what I did
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Hi, I have updated my original post with DB schema and SQL query.  I am using PHP and SQLite.  Thank you!

Comment: I have added some code that may help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I think I was trying to over complicate things by using a single query whereas your multiple query route will simplify things :-)